# SQL select by week of the current month

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, select

i have two tables, shipments and entries.

I have to select and insert into another table the entries of a selected item_id=113 and the shipments of the item_id=204, my select is the sum of the entries and shipments by week of the current month and year.

i have this two queries, each for each item.

sum(cantidad_ent)=Entry quantity
fecha=Date

```
SELECT sum(cantidad_ent) Entradas_Tortilla, DATEPART(wk, fecha) Semana, DATEPART(m, fecha) Mes, DATEPART(yy, fecha)
FROM entradas
where id_articulo=113
and month(fecha)=month(getdate()) and year(fecha)=year(getdate())
GROUP BY    DATEPART(wk, fecha), DATEPART(m, fecha), DATEPART(yy, fecha)
order by DATEPART(wk, fecha), datepart(m, fecha)
```

sum(cant_sale)=Shipment quantity

```
SELECT sum(cant_Sale) Salidas_Costales, DATEPART(wk, fecha) Semana, DATEPART(m, fecha) Mes, DATEPART(yy, fecha)
FROM salidas
where id_articulo=204
and month(fecha)=month(getdate()) and year(fecha)=year(getdate())
GROUP BY    DATEPART(wk, fecha), DATEPART(m, fecha), DATEPART(yy, fecha)
order by DATEPART(wk, fecha), datepart(m, fecha)
```

They return

```
Tortillas_entries/Week/Month/Year
      4503        27    7    2013
      3822       28    7    2013

FlourSack_shipments/Week/Month/Year
      7             27    7    2013
      6             27    7    2013
```

Wen send the flour sacks from the warehouse and they are processed into tortillas and then we do an entry from the tortillas made. This queries are made so i know how many tortillas and flour sacks are sent and made a week and i also have to register how many tortillas were made for the total of sacks a week

> (tortillas_entries/flour sacks) as Rendimiento (Production performance)
>   4503/7 3822/6

The total of tortillas entered and sacks sent are registered at the same time, so the same day we have how many sacks were sent and how many tortillas were made from those sacks.

The result im looking for would be something like this:

```
Tortillas_entries/FlourSack_Shipment/Performance/Week/Month/Year
      4503                7             643.28    27    7    2013
      3822                6              637      28    7    2013
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is `fecha` type datetime or date?

Comment: Smalldatetime @mr.Reband

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH My_CTE (Entradas_Tortilla, Semana, Mes, Ano) AS
(
SELECT sum(cantidad_ent) AS 'Entradas_Tortilla'
    ,DATEPART(wk, fecha) AS 'Semana'
    ,DATEPART(m, fecha) AS 'Mes'
    ,DATEPART(yy, fecha) AS 'Ano'
FROM entradas
WHERE id_articulo=113 and month(fecha)=month(getdate()) and year(fecha)=year(getdate())
GROUP BY DATEPART(wk, fecha)
    ,DATEPART(m, fecha)
    ,DATEPART(yy, fecha)
)
SELECT m.Entradas_Tortilla
    ,sum(s.cant_Sale) AS 'Salidas_Costales'
    ,CAST(m.Entradas_Tortilla AS REAL)/CAST(sum(s.cant_Sale) AS REAL) AS 'Performance'
    ,Semana
    ,Mes
    ,Ano
FROM My_CTE m INNER JOIN salidas s ON m.Semana = DATEPART(wk, s.fecha)
    AND m.Mes = DATEPART(m, s.fecha)
    AND m.Ano = DATEPART(yy, s.fecha)
WHERE s.id_articulo=204 and month(s.fecha)=month(getdate()) and year(s.fecha)=year(getdate())
GROUP BY Entradas_Tortilla, Semana, Mes, Ano
ORDER BY Ano, Mes, Semana
```

Hopefully I didn't make a typo or leave something out.  There may be more elegant ways of doing this than using a common table expression, but I think this will work for you.  Test it well though, and let me know if I messed up :-)  EDITED - yep, forgot to Cast the integers as real so they could be divided; fixed now

Comment: Thank you, i tried it and it works perfectly, have a nice day!! =)

Answer (score 0):

An `INNER JOIN` like this should work:

```
SELECT 
    sum(e.cantidad_ent) Tortillas_entries, 
    sum(s.cant_Sale) FlourSack_Shipment, 
    sum(cast(e.cantidad_ent as decimal(6,2))) / sum(s.cant_Sale) Performance,
    DATEPART(wk, e.fecha) Semana, 
    DATEPART(m, e.fecha) Mes, 
    DATEPART(yy, e.fecha)
FROM entradas e
inner join salidas s on 
    DATEPART(wk, e.fecha) = DATEPART(wk, s.fecha) AND 
    DATEPART(m, e.fecha) = DATEPART(m, s.fecha) AND 
    DATEPART(yy, e.fecha) = DATEPART(yy, s.fecha)
where e.id_articulo=113
and s.id_articulo=204
and month(e.fecha)=month(getdate()) and year(e.fecha)=year(getdate())
GROUP BY    DATEPART(wk, e.fecha), DATEPART(m, e.fecha), DATEPART(yy, e.fecha)
order by DATEPART(wk, e.fecha), datepart(m, e.fecha)
```

SQLFiddle example found [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/726b3/1)

Comment: the values returned are not correct, but thank you for your time, have a nice day!